# How do I generate a SQL script from my diagram in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I've created an EER diagram with tables, foreign keys, etc in MySQL Workbench and now I want to generate a ".sql" script that will create this database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try: `File->Export->Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script`