# How do I generate a SQL script(s) [file separated] from my diagram in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

When investigation
I found following answer
[How do I generate a SQL script from my diagram in MySQL Workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088360/how-do-i-generate-a-sql-script-from-my-diagram-in-mysql-workbench)

BUT its generate ALL database tables code into ***ONLY ONE single SQL script***

Any Help to generate the database tables code into ***Multi Separated SQL script(s)***

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to exclude or include a specific database in the output script, however you can use a workaround. On the SQL Object Export Filter page you can determine which objects to export. Since it supports multiselection and is sorted alphabetically (so all objects from one schema stay together) you can quickly collect object lists for each schema.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mike ... can you show how you open this wizard (using MySQL Workbench)

Comment: This is simply the Export to SQL function, which you mentioned in your question (File -> Export -> Forward Engineer to SQL Create Script...).

Answer (score 0):

Open (Data Export) by selecting following menu item
`Server -> Data Export`

Then

1. Choose your DB schema and its tables which need to be exported
2. Choose `Dump Structure Only`
3. Choose Export option `Export to Dump project folder`
4. Finally after customize your export .. click `start export`